# please how to rotate a matrix $5\times4$ by 45° around the origin $(0,0)$? using matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

Suppose I have a matrix $M$ of $5\times4$ dimension (this is represent an image) :

```
M =  [3 4 8 9; 
      1 6 7 3;
      9 8 3 1;
      1 2 2 0;
      7 2 3 5];
```

I would like to rotate it around the origin $(0,0)$ with an angle of 45°.

From what I have found on the net , I have to multiply $M$ by *Rotation Matrix* $R$ is as 
follow :

```
R = [ cosd(45) -sind(45); 
        sind(45) cosd(45)]
```

Now do I simply multiply M by R and get a rotated matrix ??? like this :

```
rotM = R*M
```

I think I will have a problem of dimensions ? please how to rotate a matrix $5\times4$ by 45° around the origin $(0,0)$?

---

### UPDATED

Here is an example of an Image (like M) that is rotated 45° around the center of the image : 
[image]

What I want to be specific is to get a rotation around the origin (0,0) of 45° (or different angle).

*PS*: imrotate, rot90, flip* and rotate is not suitable here, thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to rotate? The $R$ above will rotate a point $(x,y)$ around the origin in the plane. What does $M$ represent the values of pixels at integer coordinates?

Comment: Is your $5\times 4$ matrix supposed to represent a $4$-pointed object in $5$-dimensional space?

Comment: the values in *M* represent Heights, they are pixels of grayscale image. I will show you by a screenshot what I want to get @copper.hat

Comment: @Bye_World no I made a mistake I didn't explained well what I want , wait a minute I will update my question ...

Comment: I hope I am more specific now, I updated my question by what I want to get.

Comment: You need `imrotate`. You cannot rotate an image by multiplying it with rotation matrix. You can rotate vectors with rotation matrix, but the problem is different

Comment: B = imrotate(A,angle) rotates image A by angle degrees in a counterclockwise direction around *its center point* . it rotates around the center point what I want to get is around the origin point.

Comment: @OSryx Did you look at the tformarray function in Matlab?

Comment: @Louis no, this is new ....

Comment: the origin of the rotation is not essential, it affects only padding

Comment: you mean I can only use `imrotate` to rotate the image around the origin (0,0). How to do so please in code ?

Comment: @Louis It may be possible using `imtransform` ... I am looking on that right now.

Comment: @uranix suppose I use `B=imrotate(A,45)` now I get  something like in the screenshot in the Question. Do I have to translate back to (0,0) ??

Comment: Here is a solution : 
T = [cosd(45), sind(45), 0;...
      -sind(45), cosd(45), 0;...
      0, 0, 1];
tform = maketform('affine', T);
I2 = imtransform(I,tform);

Comment: @uranix you may be right about using only `imrotate`....

Comment: thank you for your advices ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I am answering myself since I was not 'clear' about what I want to get.

When I used a *M* matrix , I make reference to an *Image Matrix*.

So by rotation I mean create a real rotation by 45° in order to get something like the on in the following figure.

Any way here is a snippet that I succeeded to do and its result in the picture :

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');

figure(1);
subplot(2,2,1);
imagesc(I);


T = [cosd(45), sind(45), 0;...
      -sind(45), cosd(45), 0;...
      0, 0, 1];
tform = maketform('affine', T);
I2 = imtransform(I,tform);

subplot(2,2,2);
imagesc(I2);



I3 = imrotate(I,-45);
subplot(2,2,3);
imagesc(I3);
```

Image :

[image]

Comment: Glad that you were able to answer this yourself. I'd suggest using `axis image` for each subplot so that the pixels are rendered as square (1-to-1 aspect ratio).

Comment: When I use `axis image` nothing changed ... ?

Comment: Did you add it right after calling `imagesc` in the code above? The `'cameraman.tif'` is square (256-by-256 pixels) so `axis image` will make it look square when you use `image` or `imagesc`.

Comment: it was not above, maybe you are right, I can't see any differences ...?

Comment: @OSryx Try `axis equal` to make the pixels square.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rotation matrix to rotate the pixel coordinates, but then you still need to interpolate the image onto the new coordinates. Suppose your coordinates are in the matrices `x` and `y`, so that pixel $(m,n)$ is at location `(x(m,n), y(m,n))`. If your rotation matrix is `R = [ cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta) ]`, then you can get the new coordinates by converting the coordinates to a $2 \times P$ matrix where the $i^{th}$ column is the location of the $i^{th}$ pxiel and then multiplying it by the rotation matrix:

```
xy_rot = R * [ x(:)'; y(:') ];
x_rot  = reshape( xy_rot(1,:), size(x) );
y_rot  = reshape( xy_rot(2,:), size(y) );
```

This will apply the rotation to each column (i.e., each pixel location). We then separated the new $x$ and $y$ for convenience. Now that you know the new location of each pixel, you can interpolate the image to them:

```
img_rot = interp2( x, y, img, x_rot, y_rot );
```